# Detect that a hidden form field has changed?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, security, hidden-field

I am using a hidden form field to store the current record that an user is editing. How can I prevent the user from changing that field? Would MVC3's anti-forgery helpers work, or do I need to roll my own checks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than trying to check if the user changed anything, you should check that they are permitted to edit what ever record is indicated by the ID submitted.

If they are allowed to edit the ID in question, let them do it. If not, don't. Don't even bother worrying about whether they have changed the form data, which is trivial to do.

Antiforgery tokens don't really serve any purpose then, btw.

Answer (score 0):

See [How to detect if form field has changed without using hidden field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5793033/how-to-detect-if-form-field-has-changed-without-using-hidden-field)

Suggestions there are to use a hash and compare on postback to check if changes have been made.

Comment: The answer mentioned storing it in the view model. Does that refers to the ViewBag?

Comment: Because of the way MVC works the ViewBag will only be there for the lifecycle of the page. You can write the viewmodel to the page (as a hidden field). You could write the field to session (bit messy though).

Answer (score 0):

### Edit

Seems I misunterstood your question, sorry.
Indeed, AntiForgeryToken won't help you prevent that.
You can either store these non-editable informations in your Model (in my example the Account class) without exposing it or in your Session. You can also put some checking/event-raising in your model's properties to detect unwanted edition.

### Old-misunterstood-answer

You can use the HtmlHelper method [HtmlHelper.AntiForgeryToken](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470175.aspx)

1/In your form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "User", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Account</legend>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </div>

        //Your other fields

        <p>
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

2/ In your Post action method:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(Models.Account account)
```

Take note that AntiForgeryToken only works with POST request and that cookies must be (obviously) enabled :).

Comment: I know of the anti-forgery helpers. The question is does the helper helps with the prevention of tampering with hidden form fields?

Comment: Indeed, my mistake, I should have read your question another couple of times :) ! Just edited my answer.

Answer (score -1):

For prevent CSRF attacks, you can use Html.AntiForgeryToken helper method in your form section

Comment: This question is not about csrf attacks.